# Post array with ajaxForm plugin

Tags: php, jquery, ajaxform

I'm using this plugin --> http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

But I can't post an array to a PHP script.

I tried this in the beforeSubmit function:

```
var concepts = new Array();
$('#myTable tbody tr td span.file').each(function(){
  concepts.push($(this).text());
});
arr.push({name: 'concepts',value:concepts});
```

And this in the data parameter:

```
data: {
  concepts: function(){
    var concepts = new Array();
    $('#myTable tbody tr td span.file').each(function(){
      concepts.push($(this).text());
    });
    return concepts;
  }
}
```

But I always receive a comma separated string in the PHP script not an array like in any ajax call.

```
[concepts] => 20 Bafles J8 DB Line Array, 4 Bafles J12 DB Line Array, 10 Bafles J SUB, 12 Bafles B2 DB, 2 Bummpers J, 4 Bafles Q7 DB Front Fill, 12 Monitores M4 DB, 38 Amplificadores, Sub Snake, 6 Bafles Q1 DB Side Fill, 6 Bafles Q SUB DB, Centro de Carga,Andamio de 4 mts. de altura brandeados por los 4 lados con lona mesh a 1,200 dpis
```

The above is the result of:

```
print_r($_POST)
```

The array has 2 elements in this example.

But my posted data has commas. I know that I can encode to JSON and then decode inside PHP script but, I prefer to send and receive an array. Is there any way to achieve this?

I tried using processData as false, and nothing :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your example for the `beforeSubmit` function you seem to be pushing multiple values under the same input name without declaring it as an array (if that make sense). See the updated example:

```
var concepts = new Array();
$('#myTable tbody tr td span.file').each(function(){
  concepts.push($(this).text());
});

// Added square brackets to the `name` attribute
arr.push({name: 'concepts[]',value:concepts});
```

If that doesn't work, I would try sending the data to the server without the `ajaxForm()` plugin. For example:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();

  $('#myTable tbody tr td span.file').each(function(){
    data.push({name: 'concepts[]', value: $(this).text()});
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: '/post/endpoint/example', // Change me!
    method: 'post',
    data: data
  });

  return false;

});
```

If posting without the plugin works then I would assume the plugin is trying to be overly clever and doing some weird serializing to the form data.

Comment: I tried you're first suggestion, but then it prints it like an array but with one sole element: [concepts] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2 SALONES PARA 30 PERSONAS,Copia de CD de 1-100 (Impresión con inyección de tinta, estuche slim)
        ). Trying the second suggestion....

Comment: The second suggestion didn't work, again an array with one sole element. But I've made this in other projects, maybe the JQuery version changed this behaviour? I'm using V.3.2.1

Comment: My mistake, the second suggestion worked, thanks a lot!